# Landscape orientation for one view controller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, orientation

I want to show one view controller in both orientation in iPhone. And when the screen is opening the preferred orientation should be portrait only. Then according to the device orientation it'll rotate. I found some solution and the screen is rotating too. But when I'm entering the screen it is auto rotating to landscape and than I've to manually rotate it to portrait.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and 
supportedInterfaceOrientations like:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
}
//You don't actually need to implement this as UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown is the default for iPhone
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```